# In Microsoft Project, the values for my Work column appear to be wrong

Tags: ms-project, planning, resource-planning, ms-project-2016

I'm just getting started with Microsoft Project and I'm using it to plan out a project we have. There are several tasks on it where I would like the whole team (5 people) to work on a Task. My understanding is that if I put 5 Resources, each at 100% Units, on a Task it would make the Work be 5 times as much as the Duration. This was the case when I initially entered these Tasks, but when I came back to them later (after working on other tasks) I noticed that the Work is now the same as the Duration.

[image: Screenshot]

(Bonus, the one at the bottom seems to have a completely arbitrary relationship between Duration and Work)

If I manually change the Work value to what it should be and then choose "Increase the hours resources work per day (units) but keep the same duration." then it sets 4 of my resources to 0% and the remaining resource to 500%. Changing all resources back to 100% makes the Work equal to the Duration again.

I think this issue started after I clicked "Level All" in the Resources menu, but I didn't notice the exact moment so I can't be completely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the resources from the task and re-added them and it fixed the issue. I think the issue actually started when I used copy/paste to duplicate these items, as they occur twice within the project. The original worked fine, but the pasted copy had this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between Work and Duration can be controlled in a couple of different ways.
Effort driven vs non-effort driven and task types of Fixed Units (default), Fixed Duration, or Fixed Work.

In your scenario -

> My understanding is that if I put 5 Resources, each at 100% Units, on
>   a Task it would make the Work be 5 times as much as the Duration.

is true as long as the task is not effort driven and as long as none of the team has non-working time in their calendar.

it sounds as if you have resolved your issue by re-building the assignments, but you may find that working with the task form in the lower pane helps explain some issues as it will show each resource assigned and the amount of work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually didn't have to rebuild the assignment, just remove and re-add the resources. I think it was bugged.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  By removing and re-adding the resources you did rebuild the assignments.  In Project an assignment = task + resources.

Comment: Aha, I see. If the problem occurs again I will try using the task form in the lower pane. Thanks!